# Save values into an array from a function which is called consecutively

Tags: javascript

I have a function which is called when a file is needed to be read in a folder. In this case since i have 3 files in that folder, it is called 3 times consecutively. I need to save all files info into array `mapped_data2` like that:

```
mapped_data2[0] = inner_data1 //first file info, 
mapped_data2[1] = inner_data2 //second file info etc.
```

However using my code i am having just the first files information 3 times. I am a bit confused with global variables, if you can point out the problem, i would appreciate it.

here is the code:

```
var mapped_data = [];
var mapped_data2 = [];                   
function o(msg) {                    
     if (msg.data) {
         var inner_data = [];
         var lines = msg.data.split('\n'); //read lines of a file
         for (var i = 2; i < lines.length; i++) {
              if (lines[i].length > 0) {
                  .. //do same data format here
                  inner_data.push([son, vactual, voutput]);    
              }  
         } 
     mapped_data = inner_data;   
     } 
     else {
         if (msg.topic == "/somefolder/somefolder") {
                  for (var i = 0; i < msg.args.length; i++) {
                  var filename = msg.args[i];
                  aw.get(filename);
                  }
         } 
     }
}

function de() { //where i wanted to use these files info
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         mapped_data2[i] = { key: "Group" + (i + 1), values: mapped_data };
    }

    var datam = mapped_data2;
    var den = JSON.stringify(datam);
    document.write(den);
};

function init() {
                  ..//create new client called aw for the server application and start it;
                  ..//if the connection is established:  
                  aw.onmessage = o;
                  aw.get("/somefolder/somefolder"); // request list of files in a folder                         
                 };
//when html page is being onload, call the functions init() and de()
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function "o(msg)"? I don't see where the files are being read for processing.

Comment: As already pointed out, you should show the code for the reading part. I guess it's a series of asynchronous GET requests (and you're calling the function repeatedly before they end).

Comment: @Aioros Hi, I added those parts, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mapped_data2 = [];                   

function o(msg) {
     var mapped_data = []; // this doesn't need to be global
     if (msg.data) {
         var inner_data = [];
         ...             
         mapped_data = inner_data;   
     } else {
         ...
     }

     mapped_data2.push({ key: "Group" + mapped_data2.length + 1, values: mapped_data };)
     // do more stuff as in den()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I couldn't make it work here, since in de() function i cannot call o() to be values. It requires parameter and msg is not defined inside that function.

Comment: @sgizm See updated answer; you can move the contents of `de()` in `o()`.